# Bootstrap adaptive Form not playing nice with Kendo multiselect

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, select, kendo-ui, twitter-bootstrap-form

I am using "Bootstrap responsive form" (http://www.bootply.com/jrNvaahcOh) and Kendomultiselect (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index)

The Bootstrap form scales the whole form, adapting the placement (and width) of form fields based on screen size.

My example works with the form only: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/12239/

It does

1. Draw the adaptive form
2. Wait 2 seconds
3. Activate Kendomultiselect (problem here!)

Problem: When there are two columns of form fields (I assume it breaks whenever the kendomultiselect is rightmost), the Kendomultiselect messes up the "flow" of design -> It seems like the next element get's thrown off it's proper placement and is not where it should be.[image]

The Kendo Code that activates the simple html select is

```
$("#food").kendoMultiSelect().data("kendoMultiSelect");
```

..currently setup with timeout of 2 seconds to show the effect in my example.

Can anyone point out why this happens? I can only assume Bootstrap's css has problems with Kendo's css.

Comment: It looks fine to me, using the current firefox.

Comment: Make the "Result" window so that there is space for two columns. Then look what happens to the "watch this" and the next input -> the next input is pushed and there is an "empty form-cell"